# Testing for Differences in Two Datasets

Tags: data-mining

Assume that I have a dataset that contains the dates that measurements were made on a group of people. Thus, unique people identifiers, measurement results, and dates of measurements are available.  Now assume that I have a another version of the same dataset from a different source, and that there are differences between the two datasets. Is there a statistical test that can be used to tell if the differences between the two datasets are statistically significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two datasets that are supposed to be the same data then testing for significance is silly - if there is the slightest possibility that the differences could be significant, then at least one of the data sets is junk, unless the data sets are so huge that even negligible differences are significant.

You have 'data mining' as a tag. Do you have some huge amount of data?

What you should be doing, in nearly all cases anyway, is looking at and trying to explain the differences, not seeing whether they are significant

Comment: One dataset can have "12/1/1958" and the other "12/2/1958" for the same record, or one can have 0.32 for a measurement and the other 0.29 for the same record. The datasets are "historic" and it is not practical to determine which is the correct one or explain the differences. There is a fair amount of data (not huge), but I chose data-mining as the tag because I was really unsure how to tag this question.

Comment: OK, well, even with this, statistical significance is not the issue. You might want to take the mean, or just use one data set. Even if you found significant differences (unlikely) then what?

Comment: If some logical, objective criterion says that the two datasets are very similar, then I can continue my analysis with one of them. On the other hand, if the two dataset are very dissimilar, then I can't do the analysis with either until I can explain why they are dissimilar.

Comment: Significance isn't going to provide that logical objective test. You have to use a substantively based, subjective test.

Answer (score 1):

You have the entirety of both datasets, so it would not make sense to do a statistical test.  For example if you tried to test

Ho: the datasets are not different

Ha: the datasets are different

and you find even one difference between the datasets, they are different and Ho would be rejected with certainty (p-value = 0; the probability you find a difference given Ho is true would be zero).  Whether or not the datasets are the same is a deterministic property that can be observed, no need to test it.

Comment: This paper discusses joining datasets based on their "similarity"(http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/76166/ssjoin.pdf). Along this line of thought, is there a way to use such techniques to say that two datasets are very similar or that they are not very similar at all? Can we say this in some quantitative way?

Comment: Are the "unique people identifiers" correct in both datasets (i.e. is person101 in dataset A the same individual as person101 in dataset B)?  If so, you could simply find the proportion of fields that are consistent between the two datasets.  That would be a simple way to measure the similarity between the two datasets in a quantitative way, and it is easy to interpret.  You could even make the statement that X% of the entries in dataset A have different values in dataset B.  You could then decide how to handle the differences.